# REVERSE function returns just a single char

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using the built in REVERSE function on a nvarchar I expect '51.02' to be returned but instead receive 2.

```
DECLARE @HourMins nvarchar = '20.15'

SELECT REVERSE(@HourMins) digs
```

Can anyone tell me why?

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 1):

Always include a length with `varchar()` and related types!!!

```
DECLARE @HourMins nvarchar(255) = '20.15';
```

The default varies by context.  In this context, the default is `1`, which is clearly not enough for five characters.

Answer (score 1):

you need a size for the nVarchar -

```
DECLARE @HourMins nvarchar(5) = '20.15'
SELECT REVERSE(@HourMins) digs
```

-- 51.02 result